# How to fix sharing violation error in dreamweaver?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

While saving the html files sometime I get an error message in dreamweaver which is below given:

*encountered a sharing violation while accessing in dreamweaver*

I don't see this error always and also this error is particular for one set of files but I couldn't find the reason. Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: Questions: (1) Does it happen after you have already saved once this file, or can happen on the first save? (2) Can you temporarily disable the antivirus? (3) Do you have an automatic backup program working in the background?

Comment: #1- Yes it happens with existing files and not in the first save.
#2- I am not system admin so I can't, most probably they won't do.
#3- Sorry I don't know about it. but I assume no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this happen once with the McAfee anti-virus, while saving a file repeatedly.
In my case, the anti-virus took several long seconds to analyze the file,
while holding an exclusive lock to the file and so blocking all updates.

This became problematic, where a sequence such as this could fail on no access:

```
del /path/file
copy /path2/file2 /path/file
```

because during the delete the anti-virus held a lock on the file name for
several seconds.

The only solution in my case was to demand from the administrator to uninstall
the anti-virus on this virtual machine, which might not be applicable to your case.

This can also happen with an over-ambitious backup program on the NAS,
holding a read lock during the backup of the file, which prevents the save
from getting an exclusive lock.

What you could also do is wait several seconds, then try the save again, hoping that
the file will now be free of locks.